# Como explicar o significado e o uso da interjeição "eu, hein"?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, interjeições

Fui perguntado por um falante nativo da língua inglesa, qual o significado e quando usar "eu, hein!".  Inicialmente respondi que era uma interjeição, mas não soube explicar exatamente quando um falante nativo de pt-BR a usaria.  Pensei em responder que é uma interjeição usada quando presenciamos uma ação a qual reprovamos.  Mas, imediatamente, percebi que não serviria para muitos casos. Por exemplo, ao ver alguém furando uma fila eu não diria isso. Ao ver um indivíduo ser espancado, eu também não diria "eu, hein!".  Da mesma forma, ao presenciar alguma coisa muito estranha, só seria idiomático em alguns casos.  Como explicar o que significa e quando usamos?

Answer (score 2):

Lembrando que "hein" ou "[hem](https://dicionario.priberam.org/hem)" é uma interjeição para surpresa ou interrogação, a expressão "Eu, hein" questiona ou rejeita em primeira pessoa.

Ou seja, penso que expressa rejeição, desagrado pessoal, possivelmente com certo espanto. Significados que me vem à mente incluem:

- "credo"
- "quero distância disso"
- "como pode algo assim?"
- "comigo não"

Exemplos encontrados no [Corpus do Português](https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/now/) que me parecem confirmar essa interpretação incluem:

> - Eu, hein! Isso são termos para uma senadora de a República usar?
> - quem sou eu para querer apaziguar algo? Eu, hein. Seja felizes eles lá, e nós aqui
> - Que coisa malfeita é essa? Eu, hein.
> - já teria morrido de tristeza e dor. Eu, hein?! Imagina se eu vou dar a essa gente desqualificada este prazer?

Depois de ter escrito os parágrafos acima lembrei de consultar um dicionário, e no final das contas o [Wiktionary](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/eu,_hein) já tem uma ótima definição:

> #### Locução interjetiva
>
> ##### eu, hein
>
> 1. expressa estranheza, estranhação, estranhamento
>
>    - *A: Eu gosto de comer estrogonofe gelado com purê de manga e recoberto de pedacinhos de jiló frito e de acompanhamento um suco de jaca. B: **Eu, hein**.*
> 2. expressão de repulsa, aversão, o não desejo
>
>    - *Escargô? Comer lesma? **Eu, hein!***
> 3. expressa um misto de estranheza, estranhação, estranhamento com repulsa, aversão
>
>    - ***Eu, hein**, podia jurar que essa cadeira estava lá naquele canto da outra sala, vamos embora desse lugar abandonado, já estou ficando cabreiro, não estou gostando, aqui é sinistro.*

Complementado por alguns dos registros do [dicionário informal](https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/eu+hein/).

Comment: o dicionário informal cita "to fora", como um dos significados.  Por exemplo:  a) Ela disse que vai cobrar duzentos Reais de cada um que for à sua festa.  b) Eu hein! Que cara de pau.